# Canvas.DrawBitmap() doesn´t draw anything on android!! :(

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

i´m trying to make a game, but im stuck on the drawing.....

i make a custom surfaceView (with a draw() and update() methods) and my game loop(updating and drawing the view).

Everythong goes perfectly until i use the method Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint p), becuase when i try to draw, for example :

```
Canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, null, new Rect(100, 100, 200, 150), null);
```

it doenst draw anything!! but here is the wearest part, if i put sumething like this:

```
Canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, null, new Rect(0,0,100,150), null);
```

it draw it perfectly as it has to be!!!! and if i put something like this:

```
Canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, null, new Rect(50,0,100,150), null);
```

it forms like limits, i mean, thas everything over the(for example, becuase im not sure how many pixels) 100px height doesn´t apear!!! i have tried many ways, PLEASE!!! can you help me!!!

(PD: My native language is spanish, i sorry if my text have some issue.)

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter to any `Canvas#draw` methods as an object of `Paint` class. Without it, Canvas cannot do any drawing.

Before you do any drawing, initialize a `Paint` object with `Paint paint = new Paint()` and pass it to the `Canvas#draw` method. Remember to `null` the Paint object when you're done drawing, as it takes up a lot of memory.

Comment: i do it, but stil have those "limits", in this time, y modify me app, the image will be draw in a x and a y, originali 0 and 0, for in every touch, it will get coords of the touch and set the x and y there, but the image draws onle in a "invisible rectangle" , if i touch out of it, it doesnt draw it!!! :( its very wear....

Comment: The documentation say about the 4th parameter:   
Paint: May be null. The paint used to draw the bitmap.  I think 'null' means 'use all default values' i.e. the same as "new Paint()".